# How to use distinct in sub select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I have trouble to get distinct count of **`column`**.
The result I get right now is total of all not different ones.
This select is as a sub select

```
select count (distinct tss.Deliverypostadre) from Shipment tss
where  tss.DATAAREAID='wh' and tss.PARTITION=1234) as client_count
```

And if I just go using distinct

```
distinct s.Deliverypostadre as Client_count
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 105 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'distinct'.

can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Your 1st query should work fine.

Comment: Sounds like a conceptual issue. Remember that `distinct` modifies the entire results of a query (or subquery), not just a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Check below query

```
Select ..in (select count(distinct tss.Deliverypostadre)  as client_count from Shipment tss
where  tss.DATAAREAID='wh' and tss.PARTITION=1234)



 Select Code from [dbo].[Codes] where codeId in (select count (distinct Code) as code from  [dbo].[Codes])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select . . .
       (select count(distinct tss.Deliverypostadre)
        from Shipment tss
        where tss.DATAAREAID = 'wh' and tss.PARTITION = 1234
       ) as client_count
from . . .
```

Some databases might have a problem with the space between `count` and `(`.  but the syntax basically looks correct.